# vim insert-mode autocomplete using viminfo, recently opened files, sorted by word frequency

Tags: dictionary, vim, completion, mru

vim completion looks in dictionary, thesaurus and other buffers, but not the registers and mru files - I can do it by opening .viminfo and other most recently used files in background buffers. Can this be automated in vim.

Also the completion (huge linux) dictionary is sorted alphabetically. Can we see the choices sorted by usage frequency - to see the most common word first, so easier to pick the completion (like google suggest).

Comment: What about a plug-in called ctrl-p

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim, ctrl-p looks like a file finder - it doesn't look at file contents for completion in insert mode.

Comment: Not exactly to autocomplete, but to help you open files faster there is 
[fasdcd:](https://github.com/clvv/fasd)